# What is the difference between cipher algorithms AES and AES_128

Tags: android, encryption, encryption-symmetric

According to documentation for app developers **AES_128** and **AES_256** are supported from api 26. https://developer.android.com/reference/javax/crypto/Cipher. For example now I'm using **AES**(**GCM** mode) with 128 bit key. What is the difference between **AES** with 128 bit key and **AES_128** ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no difference between `AES` with a `128-bit` key and `AES_128`.

As you can see in the docs you linked, previous to `API 26` there existed one primitive for AES, with various padding options/modes of operation.

To make things simpler, in `API 26+` there is now two primitives to disambiguate the usage of `AES` with either a definitive `128-bit` or `256-bit` key.

If you are using `AES`, you should opt for `AES-256 GCM` as it provides a authenticated encryption, ensuring that the ciphertext cannot be tampered with, without the recipients knowledge.

`AES-GCM` operates with a 32-bit counter, so unfortunately with the same key, nonce (`IV`) pair you can only safely encrypt ~ `64GB` of data (`2^39-256 bits`).

If you want to move to an even safer cipher, I recommend `XSalsa20` or `XChaCha20`, which provide a `192-bit` nonce size, effectively allowing a practically "unlimited" amount of data to be encrypted with the same key, nonce pair.

Answer (score 1):

`AES_128` doesn't exists. However, constants in Java don't generally use the hyphen (`-`) character, so the underscore is used to indicate AES-128 (still a strange choice for a `String` if you ask me).

AES-128 is just AES *configured* to use a 128 bit key. Internally it uses a specific sub-key derivation and 10 rounds. AES-256 has a different sub-key derivation and uses 14 rounds. AES-192 (12 rounds) isn't used much, as it has an awkward key size and it doesn't fully protect against attacks that may be applicable to AES-128.

Practically speaking there may be two differences when it comes to general usage. First of all, the API may be able to select an implementation of 128 or 256 bits of AES *before* the `init` methods are called. Secondly, I presume that the `init` method only accepts 128 bit keys when you configure `AES-128`.